# RadioButtonFor helper creates buttons with the same id, but I want to apply JQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I created with Razor 3 radiobuttons:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectType, "Checking")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectType, "Funds") 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectType, "MoneyMarket")
```

Razor created the following HTML:

```
<input id="SelectType" name="SelectType" type="radio" value="Checking" /> 
<input id="SelectType" name="SelectType" type="radio" value="Funds" /> 
<input id="SelectType" name="SelectType" type="radio" value="MoneyMarket" />
```

Now I want to use JQuery to hide some options depending on which RadioButton was checked. I cannot do it, because each radiobutton has the same Id.
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks,

z

Comment: Can;t you give the ID's yourself, something like `, new { id: "rb1" }`

Answer (score 1):

As **tymeJV** said just assign the `id` manually.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.SelectType, "Checking", new { id = "rbChecking" })
```

Comment: This would work.  However, If you are using a label wrapping the radio, then you'll want jQuery to listen for a click on the label (in my experience.)  so you could either put an id on the wrapping label, or set up your jQuery click event on the radio's parent()...

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass an ID:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectType, "Checking", new { id = "rb1" })
```

Or, for something a bit more generic, how about defining an extension method that appends the value to the name to produce unique IDs (assuming that you only have one radio button for each value)? Something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString UniqueRadioButtonFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string value)
{
    string id = String.Format("{0}_{1}", helper.NameFor(expression), value);
    return helper.RadioButtonFor(expression, value, new { id = id });
}
```

Then, you can just do:

```
@Html.UniqueRadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectType, "Checking")
```

And you'll get a unique ID.